# Exception while merge a entity with composite primary key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using a composite primary key as below,

```
    @Entity
    public class Mentor implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        private MentorPK id;
        private String email;

        public MentorPK getId() {
            return id;
        } 
        //getters and setters
     }

@Embeddable
public class MentorPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String add;
    //getters and setters
    //override equals and hashcode  
}
```

I am getting below exception while doing entityManager.merge(mentor)

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-01747: invalid
>   user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

What i am missing here?

Comment: Where is your mapping?

Comment: Using @Id annotation

Comment: Read about mapping table and pojo in hibernate

Comment: i am using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto as create so i guess hibernate suppose to create a table for entity Mentor when server starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [description for the error](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01747.php):

> You tried to reference a column name, but the column name used is a reserved word in Oracle.

Something you use as a name is a reserved word in Oracle. In this case it seems to be the property name `add`. Map it to a different column name.

To identify the problematic attribute in cases where you don't easily identify the reserved word activate sql logging, so you get to see the problematic sql statement.

Remove the columns one, by one until the error goes away.

Rename that attribute to something that does not collide with Oracle reserved words

And here is [a list of reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm):

Answer (score -1):

```
@Entity(name=t_mentor)
```

t_mentor is your table of database. you need change t_mentor to the table of your database.  you need map Class of Mentor to table of database.

Comment: If this would be the problem it should trigger something like "table not found" not a  invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Comment: Also since i use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto as create hibernate suppose to create the table for me